# glGetShaderiv always gives me GL_FALSE

Tags: opengl, compilation, glsl

I'm a Spannish student. Now, I'm studying OpenGL in C++.

I'm learning about it but i found a problem: the function glGetShaderiv gives me GL_FALSE (but after it the shader is used by the program without problems...)

My C++ code is:

```
glShaderSource(vertID, 1, &vertCode, NULL);
glGetShaderiv(vertID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
if(!status) {
    std::cout << "Error compiling vertex shader source at file '" << vertPath << "'!" << std::endl;
}
```

The file is found well. Data is copied well (I know it because the shader is used without problems by the OpenGL program)

My GLSL Vertex Shader Source:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

void main() {
    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Please help me! Thank you very much!

Comment: Your shader is not compiled yet when you make that call. You need to place it after `glCompileShader()`.

Comment: ...
emm...uhh Ok... Thanks xD I'm a bit...